# OpenLayers 3, Markers appear in different places when viewing with iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, openlayers-3, marker

I have an OpenLayers3 map showing static map image an ontop of that a vector layer containing markers (features). The features display nicely when viewing the map on a laptop or a pc, but when viewing the map on an iPad the markers markers appear to have a some kind of offset (so that they dont't align correctly with the map). I am using pixel projection. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening? I've tested on multiple different browser (Safari and Chrome on the iPad), and I have came to a conclusion that it is not a browser issue.

Comment: Solved! The image I used was 3600x3600 pixels that was propably too much for the iPad and it was shrinked somehow  (or something..) that caused the markers to appear in a different place. I scaled the map image down to 1800x1800 and it works fine.

Comment: You should put an answer to your own question.